# How to run "sdetable register" command in SQL Server?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, enterprise-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase, sql-server

I was planning to run "sdetable register" command to register a particular field as OID for an non-spatial table already created in a SDE database. I am with SQL Server 2008 R2.

I tried to run the command 
`USE [{database}]
GO
sdetable -o register -t {table} -c {column} -C {database} -u {user} -p {password}`
from on a query window in SQL Server Management Studio.

But it logged "Incorrect syntax near 'o'." error.

Is there anything wrong with what I was doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That isn't a SQL Command, but a DOS/Command Line function you need to use to register the table. You need to launch a command prompt and use your command from after your 'GO' statement to register your table.

Comment: But just for curiosity: is there any sql command that can be run within SQL Server to register a table?

Comment: Im not aware of any single command from the TSQL syntax that could do this. As this process talks to several different tables and StoredProc; I doubt if you would want to attempt it manually.