# 'sdetable' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-10.3

I try use arcpy.JoinField_management(inFeatures, inField, joinTable, joinField, fieldList) to join SQL server database tables to shapefiles directly, using an ArcSDE connection. The database connection from ArcMap is successful.

Following the tip from 
How to run “sdetable register” command in SQL Server? at 
[How to run "sdetable register" command in SQL Server?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23291/how-to-run-sdetable-register-command-in-sql-server/23292)

I ran the command:

```
sdetable -o register -t {table} -c {column} -C {database}
```

on the desktop that ArcGIS 10.3.1 is installed.

However, it gives error message:

> 'sdetable' is not recognized as an internal or external command..

I searched "sdetable" in the desktop and didn't find some file. There are a lot of sde*** in the ArcGIS folder, but no "sdetable".

If "sdetable" command is not available for 10.3.1, is there other alternative option to join the tables? I don't prefer to export database tables to csv from the SQL Server, then import each one into ArcGIS to make it have ObjectID.

Comment: Please **edit** your question to specify which release of ArcGIS you are using.  The command-line utilities were deprecated at ArcGIS 10.2 and are no longer available at ArcGIS 10.3.  At 10.2 and before you would need to install the application server or administration tools binarie before that utility would be available.

Comment: The ArcGIS I am using is 10.3.1. so the command-line utilities is not available. what other alternatives I can use to solve this problem. Thanks

Comment: Please **edit** the question with more details about *why* you're looking to register a table.  Some don't need to be registered, some can be registered by Desktop or ArcPy, and some use cases require using the deprecated tools from a 10.2.2 install.  While you're at it, please include the 10.3.1 use **in the question**

Comment: I just edited the question. when I use arcpy to join the tables, it gives me error message: ExecuteError: ERROR 000339: Input Database Connections\Connection to ****.sde\***.dbo.*** does not have OIDs
Failed to execute (JoinField).

Comment: I don't recommend straddling ASCII, shapefile and geodatabase.  If ArcGIS creates the table, it will have been registered, so 'sdetable' use would be moot.

Comment: the database tables are created by SQL server, so they don't have OIDs. Therefore, they can't join to shapefile. I need to create OIDs on the database tables.   This process has to be automated, there are a lot of tabels

Comment: So this question really should have started with the problem, not the solution.  Please **edit the question** to provide an example of the tables you created with SQL.  You should also explain why you need to join to shapefiles when the database supports native geometry.

Comment: the shapefile I need to join the tables to is created from a spatial join in ArcGIS. Yes, SQL can do spatial join too. But because of the memory issue, SQL spatial join is toooo slow. Also, the visualization effect of shapefile in SQL server is far less than ArcGIS. I can not use SQL shapefile maps to replace ArcGIS map. These are basics about SQL spatial analysis. You should know it

Comment: @Jen Vince has been working with DBMS for a l-o-n-g time. None of that information (particularly about the shapefile being created via a spatial join) in your original question. How was he supposed to know? Maybe drastically edit this question or start a new one with the actual problem?